# How to generate a dummy GPG key by running a script for testing purposes?

Tags: gpg, nexus, n3dr

I would like to create a GPG key for testing Nexus3 and N3DR. When I follow instructions like [these](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-gpg-key), a key gets created and it could be used in the Continuous Integration (CI) as well. The question is how to create such a key while running a script. The manuals I have read so far, require manual intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the [GPG documentation:](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html)

> The command *--generate-key* may be used along with the option *--batch* for unattended key generation.